# How to include url in react table cell

Tags: json, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v6

I'm trying to use an URL as hyperlink to another field in the table.

`ticketurl` and `ticketid` are two different name value pairs in my JSON response. I'm trying to display `ticketid`, which is a hyperlink to `ticketurl`:

data is json array

```json
[
  {  
    "index": 2,
    "empId": "ammy",
    "requestorId": null,
    "profile": "a",
    "request": "b",
    "ticketId": "abc-12345",
    "createdTime": "2019-07-07 18:01:15.0",
    "updatedTime": "2019-07-07 18:56:26.0",
    "statusurl": "www.xyz.com",
    "ticketurl": "www.abc.com",
    "status": "Open",
    "description": "The issue is open"
  }
]
```

```js
<ReactTable
  data={data}
  columns={[
    {
      columns: [
        {
          Header: "Employee Id",
          accessor: "empId"
        },
        {
          Header: "Requestor Id",
          accessor: "requestorId"
        },
        {
          Header: "Profile",
          accessor: "profile"
        },
        {
          Header: "Request",
          accessor: "request"
        },
        {
          Header: "Ticket",
          id: "link",
          accessor: d => d.ticketurl,
          Cell: ({ row }) => <a href={row.ticketurl}>{row.ticketid}</a>
        },
        {
          Header: "Created Time",
          accessor: "createdTime"
        },
        {
          Header: "Updated Time",
          accessor: "updatedTime"
        },
        {
          Header: "Status",
          accessor: "status"
        },
        {
          Header: "Description",
          accessor: "description"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]}
  defaultPageSize={10}
  className="-striped -highlight"
/>
```

I'm getting an empty cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your columns object inside the ReactTable should directly have a list of your column objects, not a list of a columns list.
It should look like this :

```
columns={[
  {
    Header: "Employee Id",
    accessor: "empId"
  },
  {
    Header: "Requestor Id",
    accessor: "requestorId"
  },
  [...]
]}
```

Then, in your `Cell` content, `row.ticketid` won't return any value, since all the values are stored in `row.original`, and that you have a typo on `ticketid`, it should be `ticketId` (capital letter on the `I`).

Hence, to display the ticketId content, your `Cell` should be like this :

```
Cell: ({ row }) => <a href={row.original.ticketurl}>{row.original.ticketId}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 {
    Header: "Header1",
    Cell: ({ row }) => (
       
          <Link
            color="inherit"
            to={`/gestion-documentos/estudiante/${row.original.cedula}`}
          >
            <AiOutlineFileDone size={25} />
          </Link>
       
    ),
  },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).